# Trigger on Contact to Update Field on Account

Tags: trigger

```
public static void PopulateWelcomeKitRequested(set<Id> accIds){
    List <Account> accountsToUpdate = new list<Account>();
    list<Contact> ContactList = [select id,New_Customer_Welcome_Kit__c,AccountId,Account.Tier2__c,
                                     account.Welcome_Kits_Requested__c from contact where New_Customer_Welcome_Kit__c= true AND Id IN :accIds];

    if (ContactList <> null && ContactList.size() > 0) {
        for (Account objacc : accountsToUpdate) {
            if(objacc.Tier2__c == '1' || objacc.Tier2__c == '2'){
                if(objacc.Welcome_Kits_Requested__c <= 0)
                   objacc.Welcome_Kits_Requested__c++;   
            }
            accountsToUpdate.add(objacc);
        }

    }     
}
```

when i try to add my logic under contact trigger it says Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void PopulateWelcomeKitRequested(List) from the type ContactTriggerHandler

```
if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate){
 List <Account> accountsToUpdate = new list<Account>();
   ContactTriggerHandler.PopulateWelcomeKitRequested(accountsToUpdate);
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem/question?

Comment: code is not working as expected and gives me error

Comment: please **[edit]** your post and update with this information, additionally, you might want to review [ask] once again to improve your posts. make sure you include errors verbatim and clearly state the problem you are facing. Include what you have tried to do to actually fix the problem, debugging info, etc...

Comment: You don't seem to have your conditions as mentioned in your post implemented. Have you that implemented and its not in your post? If yes, then edit your post and also provide what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have edited the post with which what i am trying to do. and error and i am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying this method `public static void PopulateWelcomeKitRequested(set<Id> accIds){}` takes a `Set<ID> acctIds`.

You're trying to pass it a `List<Account>` that won't work you need to pass the correct `Set<ID>` to your method